# Netbeans IDE mac osx Localhost not working

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, mamp

I'm getting the following error on Netbeans IDE on osx:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8888
```

the URL is:

```
http://localhost:8888/PhpProject_130208/index.php
```

and the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Hope this works</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // put your code here
        echo "My first PHP script!";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

when I run MAMP it says MAMP is installed and working>

Needless to say I'm a complete n00b and I'm not even sure how to ask the question.  I'm trying to learn PHP on my mac and have gotten this far.

What am I doing wrong, where can I learn how to set this up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read through the [PHP Learning Trail](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/php.html) of Netbeans, this will help you with the basics.

Useful articles:

- [NetBeans IDE PHP Quick Start Tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html)
- [Setting Up a PHP Project](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html)
- [Configuring PHP, Apache, MySQL, and Xdebug for PHP development in MAC OS X](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-mac-os.html)